# How to multiply scalar by ListVector in rpy2

Tags: python, r, rpy2, scalar, vector-multiplication

I'm running the following analysis and trying to plot the inverse logit of my model:

```
R.plot(formula, data=data, ylab = 'P(outcome =  1 | outcome)', xlab = 'SURVRATE: Probability of Survival after 5 Years', xaxp = c(0, 95, 19))
a = R.coef(mod1)[0] 
b = R.coef(mod1)[1]
R.curve(invlogit(a + b*R.x))
```

`invlogit` is an R function that I am accessing via STAP.

Everything works great, but when I run the `curve` function, I get an error that `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'ListVector'`...

I've tried various ways of handling this, like using `np.multiply` among others, all to no avail. How do I handle multiplication of a scalar by a ListVector within python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kludgey solution is to just use the `rmagic` commands. It appears to be the path of least resistance to convert all my R code to the rpy2 equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

The key here is to understand that "+" and "*" are essentially R functions like any other. This means we need to "import" them too. Your example is not reproducible so I'll do my best sketching the solution:

```
import rpy2.robjects as ro
from rpy2.robjects.vectors import FloatArray
add = ro.r['+']
multi = ro.r['*']
R.curve(invlogit(add(FloatArray([a]), multi(FloatArray([b]), R.x))))
```